# How do I load a PDF from url in React with react-pdf

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

The pdf I'm loading is coming from firebase. When I try to run the program, the app renders but the pdf document fails to load.  Here are the errors:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at pdf.worker.js:1:1)
>
> Error: Setting up fake worker failed: "Cannot read properties of
> undefined (reading 'WorkerMessageHandler')".
> at api.js:2285:1

These are the npm versions:

> ```
> "@react-pdf/renderer": "^3.0.0",
>
> "react-pdf": "^5.7.2"
> ```

Here's the component setup:

```
import { Document } from 'react-pdf'

function PDFPage() {

  return (
    <div>
      <Document file={{
      url:
        'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/url-for-project-search.appspot.com/o/pdfs%2F%23000001.pdf?alt=media&token=94b5fb97',
    }} onLoadError={console.error} >
      </Document>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PDFPage;
```

Should i be loading the file from one Document's child components? What could be causing the syntax error in my node module from error 1?

The closest solution I could find was [this](https://github.com/react-pdf-viewer/react-pdf-viewer/issues/434) one. This solution is for a different npm package. I tried it but it no progress was made. here are the new errors:

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/id-to-resource'
> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/id-to-resource
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED core.js:1961 Uncaught (in
> promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'message')
> at core.js:1961:1

The alternative setup:

```
import { Worker, Viewer } from '@react-pdf-viewer/core';


function PDFPage() {

  return (
    <div style= {{height:550}}>
    <Worker workerUrl="https://unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@2.5.207/build/pdf.worker.min.js">
        <Viewer fileUrl="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/id-to-rearource" />

    ...
    </Worker>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PDFPage;
```

Comment: `'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` means you can't retrieve data from firebase using localhost

Answer (score 1):

### Below solution works for me

- **STEP 1**: Enable CORS in your cloud provider where pdf file is uploaded. In my case It was AWS and I added this for the CORS config for the bucket.

```json
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://localhost:5173" // allowing this url to use GET
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

- **STEP 2**: Fetch the pdf and render like below.

```js
const arrayBuffer = await fetch(YOUR_PDF_URL);
const blob = await arrayBuffer.blob();
const url = await blobToURL(blob);


// utils
function blobToURL(blob) {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
      reader.onloadend = function () {
         const base64data = reader.result;
         resolve(base64data);
      };
   });
}

// use the url here
return  <Document renderMode="canvas" file={url}> ...
```